# react CSS styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

so the current issue I am having is that I am unable to select an h1 for ccs, I don't fully understand why I am unable to enforce a style on the h1. I am using Sass and there should be no conflicting ccs styling for the h1 with the class name "title". if someone could explain why this is not working and how to fix the problem would be amazing. [image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding as an answer, as I can't make comments, which is what this should be.

Can you attach the entire .jsx file so that we can see how you're including the styles?

Is the `.App` styling working?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the .title {} from the .App {}

Answer (score 0):

This rules on `scss`:

```
.App{
 ....
 .title{
   ...
  }
}
```

And this is rules on CSS:

```
.App{}
.title{}
```

In `css` you should make every class individual

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that I did not have an import statement for the scss file in App.